# C# Set label.text on master page doesn't change text

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, master-pages

I want to change the label on my master page from a content page to display a confirmation note.

I get no errors, all values are as expected in debug, however the text is not changed on the screen. I've looked at numerous examples and have tried several methods but nothing seems to have the desired effect. Any ideas?

aspx:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/SLA.Master" %>
```

Master Page - SLA.Master.cs:

```
{
    public partial class SLA : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {

        public void SetMyMessage(string MyMessage)
        {
            MyMessageDisplay.Text = MyMessage;
        }
```

Content Page - SLAEdit.aspx.cs:

```
    protected void FormView1_ItemDeleted(Object sender, FormViewDeletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception == null)
        {

            Master.SetMyMessage("Service Deleted");
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?  I am having the same issue where, a master page label's text being updated inside a grid's ItemCommand event DOES update the value of the text property in the code, but does not actually get rendered.

Comment: I had the exact same situation and it turns out that because I ajaxified my Label control with Telerik Ajax, I had to add my label control from the Master page to my Ajax settings in order for it to display the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(Master as SLA).SetMyMessage("Service Deleted");
```

Comment: Thanks Troy, but nope, still looks like it's working in debug but doesn't change text on screen.

Comment: Do you change the text of that label in the Page_Load event of the master page?  One thing that has tripped me up in the past is the fact that the Page_Load event on the content pages occurs BEFORE the master page's Page_Load event...so if you do something like SetMyMessage(String.Empty) in the master page's Page_Load event that will overwrite any changes made in the content page's load.

Comment: Actually, it is in an event triggered by a delete.

Comment: Is it important where I place the SetMyMessage definition??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(Master.FindControl("MyMessageDisplay") as TextBox).Text = "Service Deleted";
```

Comment: Thanks Karl but same problem.

Comment: Hmm, can you post more of your code then, because I can run it fine with the example I provided. What is going on in your Page_Load of the content page?

Comment: I have no code at all in the Page_Load of either the master or content pages.

Comment: protected void FormView1_ItemDeleted(Object sender, FormViewDeletedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Exception == null)
            {
                    (Master.FindControl("MyMessageDisplay") as Label).Text = "Service Deleted";
                   // Master.SetMyMessage("Service Deleted");

                        Response.Redirect("SLACategories.aspx");
                }

            }

Comment: The call is invoked in Formview_ItemDeleted, then I redirect to the main page which is within the master. I assume it refreshes the text when it redirects?

Comment: Perhaps it is relevant that the label is on a panel on the master page?

Comment: If you take out the Response.Redirect call, does it update the label?

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will work:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl_TitlePage = Page.Master.FindControl("lbl_TitlePage") as Label;
    lbl_TitlePage.Text = "THE KEY QUESTIONS";
}
```